# Increment hex value of R.id file element

Tags: android, android-identifiers

i have some consecutive elements id declared inside R.java files. Now i need to fill each one by using a for cycle, so i need to increment for each iteration value of id. I've write this:

```
int current_id = R.id.button00;
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    TextView to_fill = (TextView) (getActivity().findViewById(current_id));
    to_fill.setText(String.valueOf(values[i]));
    current_id++;
}
```

but in this way current_id doesn't increment correctly.
How can i do?

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that the generated IDs in R will be sequential, or that they will be generated in any particular order.

I recommend putting your IDs in an array resource like so:

```
<array name="button_id_array">
    <item>@id/button00</item>
    <item>@id/button01</item>
    <item>@id/button02</item>
</array>
```

Then you can access it in code like so:

```
int[] ids = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.test);
```

Comment: id is ordered, it's something like:

button00=0x7f040038;
        public static final int button01=0x7f04003a;
        public static final int button02=0x7f04003c;
        public static final int button03=0x7f04003e;
        public static final int button10=0x7f040040;
        public static final int button11=0x7f040042;

Comment: The first thing to notice is that it isn't incrementing by 1 (as you have written in your code)- it is incrementing by 2. Again, I highly recommend against trying to do this as it is prone to the ID generation mechanisms that you have no control over.

Comment: Not only is incrementing hard id numbers unpredictable, but the sequence can *change* between fresh builds. I strongly agree with Tanis here. Even if you get it "working", there's no guarantee it will work later.